# Is L(H) = L(G) :: Is line graph of a hypergraph is also a line graph of a graph ??

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hypergraphs

The line graph of a hypergraph is the graph whose vertex set is the set of the hyperedges of the hypergraph $\{E_1,...E_m\}$, with two hyperedges adjacent when they have a nonempty intersection.

My question if $G$ is a line graph of some hypergraph $H$, is $G$ also a line graph of some other graph $G'$ ?

I'm pretty sure that this question has a positive answer, but I do not know how to prove it.

Any idea will be useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. $K_{1,3}$ is the line graph of the hypergraph $(\{v_1,v_2,v_3\},\{\{v_1,v_2,v_3\},\{v_1\},\{v_2\},\{v_3\}\})$ but by [Beineke's characterization of line graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#Forbidden_subgraphs) it is not the line graph of any graph.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful answer !

Comment: In fact, any graph is the line graph of some hypergraph.